# Dynamic W3C Validation

Tags: php, javascript, validation, w3c

I have a small element on my website that displays the validity of the current page's markup. At the moment, it is statically set as "HTML5 Valid", as I constantly check whether it is, in fact, HTML5 valid. If it's not then I fix any issues so it stays HTML5-valid.

I would like this element to be dynamic, though. So, is there any way to ping the W3C Validation Service with the current URL, receive the result and then plug the result into a PHP or JavaScript function? Does the W3C offer an API for this or do you have to manually code this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not have an API that I am aware of.

As such, my suggestion would be:

Send a request (`GET`) to the result page (`http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=`) with your page's URL (using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or [`curl`](http://php.net/curl)). Parse the response for the *valid* message ([`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) or simple string search).

**Note:** This is a brittle solution. Subject to break if anything changes on W3C's side. However, it will work and this tool has been available for several years.

Also, if you truly want this on your live site I'd strongly recommend some kind of caching. Doing this on every page request is expensive. Honestly, this should be a development tool. Something that is run and reports the errors to you. Keep the badge static.

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail with the code, please? I'm not as PHP-fluent as I'd like to be.

Also, why would it be expensive? I'm not doubting you, I'm just curious as I was under the impression that all processing is done server-side. The only issues I can think of that could present is if the entire process is synchronous and the W3C is particularly slow on that day.

Comment: Generally speaking, you want your page to make as few request as possible for better performance. You intend to send a request to W3C for every time your page is requested. Imagine if a lot of people did that - DoS attack on W3C. As far code, why don't decide on what you *want* to develop based on this current answer. Then ask another question with what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker (aka validator) here. In fact the checker does expose an API that lets you do, for example:

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F&out=json

…which gives you the results back as JSON. There’s also a POST interface.

You can find more details here:

- [https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-»-HTTP-interface](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-%C2%BB-HTTP-interface)
- [https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-»-Input-»-POST-body](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-%C2%BB-Input-%C2%BB-POST-body)
- [https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-»-Input-»-GET](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-%C2%BB-Input-%C2%BB-GET)
- [https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Output-»-JSON](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Output-%C2%BB-JSON)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to implement W3C API to validate HTML in PHP:

```
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => "http://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=json",
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
       CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
       CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '<... your html text to validate ...>',
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
           "User-Agent: Any User Agent",
           "Cache-Control: no-cache",
           "Content-type: text/html",
           "charset: utf-8"
       ),
   ));
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   $err = curl_error($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   if ($err) {
      //handle error here
      die('sorry etc...');
   }
   $resJson = json_decode($response, true);
```

$resJson will look like this:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "type": "error",
            "lastLine": 13,
            "lastColumn": 110,
            "firstColumn": 5,
            "message": "Attribute “el” not allowed on element “link” at this point.",
            "extract": "css\">\n    <link el=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../css/plugins/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.min.css\">\n    <",
            "hiliteStart": 10,
            "hiliteLength": 106
        },
        {
            "type": "info",
            "lastLine": 294,
            "lastColumn": 30,
            "firstColumn": 9,
            "subType": "warning",
            "message": "Empty heading.",
            "extract": ">\n        <h1 id=\"promo_codigo\">\n     ",
            "hiliteStart": 10,
            "hiliteLength": 22
        },....
```

Check [https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-»-Input-»-POST-body](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-%C2%BB-Input-%C2%BB-POST-body) for more details.